Code outputting twice when there's an input with spaces in C++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    string userIn;
    bool on = true;
    
    while(on == 1) {
        cout << ">> ";
        cin >> userIn;
        if(userIn == "quit") {
            on = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

If you input something like "Hello World" the program will output ">> >> " at the start instead of ">> ".
I was expecting it to output ">> " instead of ">> >> "

cin >> userIn will only read one word. If you want the whole line, use std::getline instead. Example

When debugging, modify the code to show the value of userIn right after the input. Knowing what the input actually is often is the key to debugging.

Side note: while(on == 1) should be written while(on).

You're a beginner so you still believe in the 'psychic compiler'. This is the compiler that knows what you want to happen instead of the real compiler that does what you tell it to do. You have assumed that cin >> userIn; reads a whole line of text, even though no-one has ever told you this (since it's not true). You'll find this kind of thing happens many times as you learn C++. You did well in diagnosing the problem (input with spaces) but you didn't take the next step of working out which of your assumptions about C++ was wrong.
